# How to create condition in NetLogo that 2 slider values cannot exceed defined value?

Tags: interface, slider, conditional-statements, netlogo, agent-based-modeling

I created a model which as 2 different sliders, namely `ratio1` and `ratio2`. They are located on the interface and their values should add up to 1 (here: `labour-unit`), and also cannot exceed this value. For now, NetLogo let's me exceed the condition.

I tried this:

```
to setup
  create-turtles number-of-turtles   ;; number of firms to be defined through slider
  set labour-unit ratio1 + ratio2
  set labour-unit 1
end
```

Therefore, my question is: How to create a condition in the setup that 2 slider values cannot exceed a defined value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there any reason you actually need two sliders if the values always add to 1? Could you just have one slider called "proportion with labor-type x" or whatever you're modelling? Then, you can just have reporters to return the values for the actual proportion you're after- for example:

```
to-report ratio1
  report proportion-slider
end

to-report ratio2
  report precision ( 1 - proportion-slider ) 2
end
```

Then on your interface you could have the slider (and monitors if needed):

[image]

Comment: This is a very smart solution. Thanks a lot!